# Mercurial list files from changegroup

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I want a simple command to get the list of files which differ after pushing to a mercurial repository on a server,
that is the differences between the previous push and the current push.
On the server, I have a hook on the changegroup event which calls a bash script.
$HG_NODE is the revision for the first commit in the changegroup.

My attempts:

```
hg status --rev $HG_NODE::
```

Exclude changes made in the first commit

```
hg status --rev $HG_NODE^1::
```

Includes changes that affected the parent revision through others pushes.

```
hg log -v --rev $HG_NODE:: | grep ^files
```

Include committed then reverted changes, still has 'files:' and files are not one per line

```
hg status --rev $HG_NODE:: && hg status change --rev $HG_NODE
```

Does not give exactly what I want, rather the change between the parent to the first commit in the changegroup + the change between this one (instead of the two changesets merged)

```
hg status --rev some_tag ; hg tag --remove some_tag ; hg tag --local some_tag
```

(Have not tried, is it a good idea?) Uses a local tag to keep track of the head for the last push, updates it each time.

Also I want to only monitor the default branch, so I assume I will use something like --rev "revision and branch(default)" or the branch option for hg log.

As to why, I need to go through the changes to determine parameters for an automated build.

Answer (score 0):

`hg stat -r` is to list the removed files. To get the list of files which differ, you should use `hg st --rev` as follows.

```
hg st -m --rev tip^:tip
```

Comment: My bad, I was actually already using --rev, I used -r in the post to shorten the code thinking it would be the same (I fixed it). I already tried with ^, but the revision parent for my case may not be the same as the previous tip